# How to move videofile elements to be side by side on mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am designing a website portfolio where a list of videos is displayed. However, on mobile, the videos are all on the left side of the screen in rows of 1. On desktop, the videos are centered in rows of three (which is the intended style). I have tried many methods, including a lot of media queries, but I can't find a solid way to display the videos properly on mobile as such

```
Professional
    Work

[Video][Video]
[Video][Video]
[Video][Video]
[Video][Video]
...
```

Here is all the code involved. Please let me know how to perform my idea, along with any improvements or suggestions for the code.

```
/* VideoFile.tsx */
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./VideoFile.css";
import { Paper } from "@mui/material";
import { useVideoContext } from './VideoContext.js';

export default function VideoFile({
    name,
    image,
    link,
    release,
    popularity,
  }: {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    link: string;
    release: string;
    popularity: number;
  }) {
    
  const { setVideoLink } = useVideoContext();

  let redirect = name;
  redirect = redirect.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  const url = `/video/${redirect}`;

  const handleVideoClick = () => {
      setVideoLink(link);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Paper
        elevation={3}
        className="video-paper"
        
        sx = {{padding: 0.5, height: 204, width: 200, '@media (max-width: 667px)': {height: 154, width: 150, paddingRight: 2.17},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 720px)': {height: 159, width: 155, paddingRight: 1.2},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 740px)': {height: 154, width: 150, paddingRight: 1.2},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 896px)': {height: 179, width: 175, paddingRight: 1.3},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 844px)': {height: 169, width: 165, paddingRight: 1.2},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 932px)': {height: 184, width: 180, paddingRight: 1.8},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 915px)': {height: 179, width: 175, paddingRight: 1.35},
                                                      '@media (max-width: 677px)': {height: 154, width: 150, paddingRight: 2.17}
                                                      
              }}
        >
            <Link to={url} state={{link}} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onClick={handleVideoClick}>
                <img
                    src={image}
                    alt={name}
                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", objectFit: "cover" }}
                />
        </Link>
      </Paper>
      <div className="img-name">{name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export { VideoFile };
```

```
/*ProfessionalProjects.js*/
import { React } from 'react';
import VideoList from '../components/VideoList.tsx'
import { Grid, Container } from '@mui/material';
import VideoFile from '../components/VideoFile.tsx';
/*import { Filter } from '../components/Filter.tsx'*/
import './Projects.css';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.tsx';

export default function Professional() {
  /*const [videos, setVideos] = useState(VideoList({ page: false }));*/ //Took out filter
  const arrayToGrid = (arr, elementsPerRow) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += elementsPerRow) {
      result.push(arr.slice(i, i + elementsPerRow));
    }
    return result;
  };
  /*const handleFilterChange = (filteredVideos) => {
    setVideos(filteredVideos)
  };*/
  const videoGrid = arrayToGrid(VideoList({ page: false }), 3);

  

  
  

  return (
    <div className="gradient_background_projects">
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <div className="title">Professional Work</div>
      <br />
      <br />
      {/*<Filter onFilterChange={handleFilterChange}></Filter>*/}
      <br />
      <Container maxWidth="md" style={{ marginTop: 16}}>
        <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ marginRight: 'auto', marginLeft: 'auto'}}>
          {videoGrid.map((row) =>
            row.map((vidData, idx) => (
              <Grid key={idx} item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <VideoFile {...vidData} />
              </Grid>
            ))
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Current [Website](https://www.coltoncaulfield.com/ProfessionalWork)

I have tried a lot of media queries.